# Web Map: two events on one marker

Tags: website-design, popup, map-ui, maps

I have a map with a store and it's clients:

[image]

I want to give the user the possibility to remove/add the clients (it can be messy with many stores/clients). So i chose to add/remove on click.

Unfortunately, I already have an event on click: a popup. So if you click to have the info in the popup, the clients disappear:

[image]

So I had two ideas:

- On mouseover, but it's annoying when the whole map is covered with markers
- On dbclick, but it's unexpected on the web

Any advice or idea?

Answer (score 1):

There's one possibility not considered in the other answers:

> Action cycling

So you could switch between the different possibilities with your `onClick` event handlers. The main event handler would initiate the stack of actions and show the first and most obvious action. Then loop through them. When you're at the end of your stack, just show the map again.

If there're actions that are for power users only, you could set an `onMouseDown` action as well that counts the `timeout` until `onMouseUp` and then shows for example options. Tap+Hold is already in use on Google Maps for example for panning and such, so it's not really a new concept and power users will get to it quite quickly.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQ6mYf.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can just implement a mode for adding/removing client which is activated with command button (menu item).

Generally speaking, make the most frequently action default and add mode for less frequently action. Command button not only changes mode but makes them obvious and also informs user of the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of possibilities:

- An "edit/use" command-button toggle as suggested [in another answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/q/41811/12718) by Alexey
- A "Remove" button or link **in your popup,** so clicking the marker allows it to be verified and then removed individually
- Use right-click on the marker for context-dependent actions like "Remove this marker"

All can be implemented in Google Maps with more or less work, and presumably in other mapping products too.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add a button ON the pop up? Makes sense to add the information, as well as the functionality together.